# Wordpress childtheme with new sub-URL

Tags: wordpress, url, themes, wordpress-theming

I have a website you can imagine it is `xyz.com` and it is built on WordPress. what I would like to do is that make a new URL for example `new.xyz.com` and use the theme which `xyz.com` has. My purpose is to make changes to `new.xyz.com` and if it was approved by supervisor i make the same changes to `xyz.com`. So what is the best approach here? I am a newbie. show I make a new URL on the go-daddy and apply the theme to it?

Comment: Please take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new subdomain "new" on your domain "xyz.com", so the new address will be new.xyz.com
Then you can install WordPress on new.xyz.com as you'd on any website. And then you can copy the theme files from */wp-content/themes* to */wp-content/themes* and make your changes there.

Or better still, you could create a staging site, by using one of the staging plugins.